# Does the following Python code execute both if and else?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
if print("welcome"):
    print("heelloo!")
else:
    print("bbye!")
```

This piece of code prints both welcome and bbye. So, is the if condition never executed, or is it something else? Kindly explain as I am fairly new to Python.

Comment: `if print("welcome")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is supposed to be a *condition* after the word `if`. You've put there a `print` function call. What the `if` statement will do is that it will call the `print` function (hence printing your "welcome") and decide whether to execute the if branch or the else branch, by looking at the return value of `print`.

`print` always returns `None`. `None` is considered a false value (so is 0 btw), so the else branch executes, printing "bye".

Answer (score 3):

The print function returns None which evaluates to False. Hence both will be printed. You can check the return value of the print function with this,

```
print(print("welcome")) # prints None which evaluates to False in if
```

Comment: `print(print("welcome"))` will print welcome first, then None.